# Error: bad username; while reading /etc/crontab

Tags: cron, rsync, nfs

I want to copy files from a server to an NFS that I've mounted on the server.

To do this I configured a crontab to copy these files to the NFS. By typing the command manually the files were copied successfully but by automating the theme with a crontab it always tells me  `Error: bad username; while reading /etc/crontab`

Here is the crontab conf :

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command

17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly

25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )

47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )

52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )

#

*/5 * * * admindp cp -r /srv/wildfly/email_templates/ /mnt/sharedfolder_client/wildfly/email_templates/

*/5 * * * admindp cp -r /srv/ma/dataprotect/sensiproImages /mnt/sharedfolder_client/sensiproImages/

*/5 * * * * admindp cp -r /var/log/tomcat8/sensiproscheduler-app.log /shared_ftp/
```

Comment: Is `adminp` the user that you are trying to run the rsync command as?

Comment: Hello , yes admindp is the user that i'm trying to run the rsync command with
it's a root user

Answer (score 5):

The specification of cron jobs in the system-wide `/etc/crontab` file is different from that in regular user crontabs. As noted in `man 5 cron`:

> ```
>    The system crontab (/etc/crontab) uses the same format, except that the
>    username  for  the  command is specified after the time and date fields
>    and before the command. The fields may be separated by spaces or  tabs.
>    The maximum permitted length for the command field is 998 characters.
> ```

**Note that the username must come immediately after the time specification**. So assuming you want to run the `rsync` command as user `admindp`:

```
*/5 * * * *     admindp     rsync -r /var/log/tomcat8/sensiproscheduler-app.log /shared_ftp/
```

Comment: Hello 
Thanks for the informations :) 
so i did the changes but it doesnt work :/

*/5 * * * * admindp rsync -r /var/log/tomcat8/sensiproscheduler-app.log /shared_ftp/

Comment: i have always the same errors

Mar 11 11:59:01 ord001 cron[24972]: Error: bad username; while reading 
Mar 11 12:22:41 ord001 cron[25100]: Error: bad username; while reading /etc/crontab
Mar 11 12:22:41 ord001 cron[25100]: (*system*) ERROR (Syntax error, this crontab file will be ignored)

Comment: Okay, so you made a syntax error - a typo. That seems unrelated to this fine answer.

Comment: @sefayoub that suggests either that `admindp` is not actually a valid username on your system (check with `id admindp` for example) or you have another error elsewhere in the file. If you are still having issues then please edit your question to include the complete `/etc/crontab` file.

Comment: @steeldriver , i just edit my question , i included the complete contab file .
admindp is a username on the system , below the result of the command id admindp : 

root@ord001:/shared_ftp# id admindp
uid=1000(admindp) gid=1000(admindp) groupes=1000(admindp),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),110(lxd),115(lpadmin),116(sambashare)

I changed also rsync to cp -r but still got the same error " bad usernam " 

Thanks for your help

Comment: @sefayoub two of your entries appear to have the wrong number of time specification fields (only 4 instead of 5)

Comment: @sefayoub although I would expect that to result in a `bad day-of-week` error rather than a bad username error.